# Entities cannot be found after update edmx file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, edmx

For the project I am working on, we have updated the database with two extra datatables that I now would like to add to the edmx file, but this gives an unwanted result.

What I do is open the edmx file, open the model Browser and run Update form database. In the wizard here I choose the two tables I want to add under the add tab and click finish.
The tables show up in the diagram view and in the Model browser under Model.Store-Tables/Views (and under Entity Types and EntityContainer). So far so good.
When I then save the changes to the edmx, all other existing entities,as well as the complete content of the Model.Context.tt file are deleted. The result being that the context entity and all underlying entities no longer can be found.

I do not understand why this is happening, and I don't know how to fix this and I am now stuck in the development of the project. i am using VS2015 and Entity Framework 6. I have spend most of the day to find a solution, but have not been able to do so. None of the "Entity can't be found" solutions around fixed my problem. I hope therefor that some smart minds here can help.

Thans!

Comment: can you check if the connection string has changed ?

Comment: i have checked the connection string in App.config, Web.config and in the properties of the edmx file before and after i added the tables and it is the same in all three situations and does not change.

Comment: FWIW, this is one of the reasons why EDMX has been deprecated. It's insanely brittle and fragile, and you often spend more time trying to debug the stupid EDMX than your actual application. I would recommend getting rid of it and switching to Code First, which despite the name, can be used with an existing database just as well. I have an article detailing how to do that if you're interested: http://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/

Comment: I read your article and it makes sense that the edmx is scrapped... I have done a little more research about the code first approach and if I understand it right it is not much more than adding mapping classes to the project, right? But How does it work for dB views and Stored Procedures?